# C++ getline() function not working as intended

Tags: c++

```
int boardDim(ifstream & inputFile, unsigned int x, unsigned int y) {
    inputFile.open("test.txt");
    if (!(inputFile.is_open())) {
        throw fileNotOpen;
    }
    else {
        stringstream output;
        string output1;
        if (getline(inputFile, output1)) {
            output << output1;
            if (output >> x) {
                if (output >> y) {
                    return success;
                }
                return secBoardVarErr;
            }
            return firstBoardVarErr;
        }
        return lineErr;
    }
    cout << x << endl;
    cout << y << endl;
}
```

The input file contains one line of two `int`s, "10 11".

I'm returning the lineErr. I can't seem to figure out why my getline() function is returning false.

Comment: Please edit your question to contain a [mcve]

Comment: Are you sure the program's not running in some unexpected directory where an old empty test.txt file exists?  Especially when running from an IDE, the current working directory may not be where you expect.  Separately, are you sure `lineErr` and `success` are distinct values?  It would be a good idea to move the `cout` statements before the `return success;` so you can see them (and know for sure whether the parsing worked).

Comment: If you want to use the values of x and y read from the file outside of this function you should pass them as references.

Comment: @TonyD, yes, I am sure. It is running a test.txt file in the same directory as the executable. Additionally, lineErr and success are distinct values- they are error enumerations declared in another header file I didn't include. I have moved the cout statements before the return success values to test my code, but it threw the same error. Thank you for your response, though!

Comment: `getline` never returns `false`.

Answer (score 2):

After you write to the `output` stream, you are at the end of the stream. To be able to read the data again, you need to seek to the beginning of the stream:

```
output.seekg(0, ios_base::beg);
```

BTW, `output` is a really bad name for a stream you are reading from.  :-)

Comment: it's not being written to the output stream in the first place, as the getline() function returns false. I will implement your solution that problem, however. Thank you!

and haha you're right, I was thinking this stream contains the final values i will be returning.

Comment: FWIW, I usually do the `getline` _then_ in the successful `if` scope create a `std::istringstream input(line);` - by providing the content during construction, you avoid the need to stream the line read.

Comment: @Harrison: _"the getline() function returns false"_ How do you know? Anyway, no, getline() never returns false.